# enum checking by class does not work

Tags: c++, enums

I have the class APD and via a vector I read in some data from a file.
For some operations I'll use an enum flag but whyever the setting of a flag works but not the checking directly afterwards.

Here's the code segment:

```
for(unsigned long int i=0; i<apdvec_filter.size(); i++) 
{
    long int APD_filter_SN_i = apdvec_filter[i].getSN(); 
    for(unsigned long int j=0; j<apdvec_database.size(); j++)   
    {   
        long int APD_database_SN_j = apdvec_database[j].getSN();    

        if(APD_filter_SN_i==APD_database_SN_j && APD_filter_SN_i!=0 && apdvec_database[j].getMatchStateString()!=APD::MATCHED)
        {
            apdvec_database[j].setMatchState(APD::MATCHED);
            cout << "SN_i: " << APD_database_SN_j << "   SN_j:" << APD_database_SN_j << "   type: " << apdvec_database[j].getMatchStateString() << endl;
        }

        if(APD_filter_SN_i==APD_database_SN_j)
        {
            // if(apdvec_database[j].getMatchStateString()==APD::MATCHED)
            {
                cout << "SN_j: " << APD_database_SN_j <<  "   type: " << apdvec_database[j].getMatchStateString() << endl;
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

This yields:

```
SN_i: 818008630   SN_j:818008630   type: MATCHED
SN_j: 818008630   type: MATCHED
SN_i: 917010242   SN_j:917010242   type: MATCHED
SN_j: 917010242   type: MATCHED
SN_i: 912009899   SN_j:912009899   type: MATCHED
SN_j: 912009899   type: MATCHED
SN_i: 906009386   SN_j:906009386   type: MATCHED
SN_j: 906009386   type: MATCHED
```

But when I enter the line `// if(apdvec_database[j].getMatchStateString()==APD::MATCHED)`

then I only get

```
SN_i: 818008630   SN_j:818008630   type: MATCHED
SN_i: 917010242   SN_j:917010242   type: MATCHED
SN_i: 912009899   SN_j:912009899   type: MATCHED
SN_i: 906009386   SN_j:906009386   type: MATCHED
```

The declaration of the enum in the header of the class APD is:

```
class APD
{
        public:
        enum MatchStateType{UNDEFINED=0,NOT_MATCHED=1, MATCHED=2};
        static string MatchStateStrings[3];
        MatchStateType getMatchState() const;
        string getMatchStateString() const;     
        void setMatchState(int a_match_state);

       private: 
        MatchStateType m_match_state;
}
```

and the declaration itself in the according cpp-file:

```
APD::MatchStateType APD::getMatchState() const
{
    return m_match_state;
}

string APD::getMatchStateString() const 
{
    return MatchStateStrings[(int)m_match_state];
}

void APD::setMatchState(int a_match_state)
{
    m_match_state=static_cast<MatchStateType>(a_match_state);
}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Well, if you filter only `MATCHED` items then you get only `MATCHED` items, what is the problem here? You may also want to properly surround comparison operations inside of `if` with parentheses.

Comment: It's unlikely anyone will be able to explain anything to you because your question fails to meet all requirements for a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help]. You need to edit your question, and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @VTT The problem is that I set the enum flag to MATCHED but when I want to filter all vector elements, which are set to MATCHED then nothing shows up

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sure, sorry, I hoped you are so fluent you will easily see it :) Give me some minutes, I upload the files.

Comment: The text "I requested a string and not the enumerator" was later added to this question, and it was labelled in the edit remarks as a solution. We're very grateful for self-answers here, although they need to be supplied below in the answer section, and not as an edit to the question (so I've edited it out). I would say also that in this case, that brief description is not very clear or detailed. If you are able to make a self-answer that is a bit more expansive, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You both posted too much code and not enough code.  If a comparison of string and enum is your question, you should focus on that, and make the code complete enough to compile.  This is neither of those.

That said, I can't tell what kind of string class you're using, but it looks like you're comparing the enumerator numerical value to the string, and expecting that comparison to be meaningful.  I'm not sure why this compiles (Guess: does your string class do some sort of numeric-to-string conversion?)

```
apdvec_database[j].getMatchStateString()!=APD::MATCHED
```

Don't you want to call getMatchState(), not getMatchStateString() ? Comparing the enumerator (2) to "MATCHED" is expected to not be equal.

Comment: Can't believe it..   neither that dumb mistake nor that someone really would discover it so fast. Thank you very much!

Comment: As you said: I also wonder why this compiles..  but I posted all of the declarations (except directly setting m_match_state=UNDEFINED;).

Comment: What string class are you using?  Not std::string, I assume.  If so, how old is this compiler?  What version is it?